# Wordpress - remove nodes for custom user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I trying to customize WP user dasboard and trying to delete/hide some features like admin bar links.

With this code i trying to remove all useless stuff:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_nodes', 999 );

function remove_wp_nodes() 
{
    global $wp_admin_bar; 
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-link' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-media' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'comments' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-page' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'new-gry' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'site-name' );
}
```

But it works for admins, not for my custom user roles, and I don't have idea why.
Even if I add conditional like:

```
if( user_can( $current_user, "gamer" ) )
```

How to fix that? "GAMERS" can't have access for example to: `/wp-admin/edit-comments.php` section.

Comment: Check user roles in your function

Answer (score 1):

You can follow  below post hop it will be use for this

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350492/hide-from-specific-role-the-top-admin-bar-new-button

**alternate solution**

You can use `WP_Role` class,

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( $role_name );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( $capability_name );

// remove $cap capability from this role object
$role_object->remove_cap( $capability_name );
```

So to address your original question about how to enable Admins to enter SCRIPT and IFRAME tags into post content, you're looking for the 'unfiltered_html' capability, which in Multisite is only granted to Super Admins.

```
// get the the role object
$admin_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
// grant the unfiltered_html capability
$admin_role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html', true );
```

or you can run this once in your functions:

```
/* Roles & Capabilities */
add_role('professional', 'Professional User', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability, False specifically removes it.
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    //'edit_published_posts' => true,
    //'publish_posts' => true,
    //'edit_files' => true,
    'upload_files' => true //last in array needs no comma!
));
```